# Play an audio with Angular 13

Tags: angular, components

I'm trying to play an audio when clicking a button with Angular 13, this button is on my main page in the default angular app.component.html file.

```
<html>
  <button class="card wrapper" (click)="playSound()">Play a Sound</button>
</html
```

The playSound() function running on the button is in my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  playSound() {
    console.log("click")
    let audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "../music.mp3";
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }
}
```

The function is called correctly, the console log of the first line of this function appears every time I click the button, but the music does not play. The file path is correct!

My music file is in src, the app.component.html and app.component.ts are in src/app

Console log:

```
click
GET http://localhost:4200/music.mp3 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
Blocked autofocusing on a <input> element in a cross-origin subframe.
```

When trying to take the responsibility off the function to find the audio location, I removed the following line:

```
audio.src = "../music.mp3";
```

And I put the src attribute directly in the button's HTML tag, modifying the tag so that it looks like this:

```
<button class="card wrapper" src="../music.mp3" (click)="playSound()">Play a Sound</button>
```

That way the console didn't register any more errors, but the music still doesn't play.

Comment: Maybe you’re not using it correctly?  https://www.delftstack.com/howto/javascript/play-audio-javascript/

Comment: What directory/folder is your music file in?

Comment: @nullptr.t my music file is in src, the app.component.html and app.component.ts are in src/app.

Comment: @Bier Okay, if it's in your `src` folder then just reference it as `/music.mp3`, because it's looking for the mp3 one level above the `src` folder, hence the 404 (resource not found) error.

Comment: @nullptr.t I tried to change this in the button tag and inside the function to src="/music.mp3" but the song still won't play

Comment: Are you getting the same error or it just does not play?

Comment: @nullptr.t The same errors, when I put the src inside the function I get the 404 error in the console as I put it above, and if I put it directly in the <button> tag I don't get any error, it just doesn't play the audio.

Comment: Then MikeOne is correct, the Audio class is not being used correctly. Please have a look at this example to see a working implementation of the Audio element.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axlxgt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @nullptr.t This code have a problem, look https://i.imgur.com/Gf5u3mK.png 
I copied and pasted the html code in my project too